# Improving the classic 18V mod for guitars

Tags: voltage-regulator, potentiometer

I am trying to figure out how to use a potentiometer or some form of fader to bring my circuit from 9 V to 18 V, and then back to 9 V without it being permanently one or the other, having to disassemble to change.

I don't want popping from an DPDT switch.

I'm wanting to be able to roll it up to 18 V when I need more headroom and then roll it back down to 9 V for a grittier sound.

What is the most efficient way to do this, what do I need? 
Before its mentioned yes the guitar has a gain boost.

Edit: the power source is two 9 V batteries rated at 540 mAh. The current draw is 1.22 mA @ 9 V total. (3 active humbuckers 0.08 mA @ 9 V each with boost preamp 0.98 mA @ 9 V.)

I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking this for the guitars with active pickups or pedals?

Comment: @RohatKılıç this is for a guitar with active pickups

Comment: "m" for milli, "M" for mega, "A" for ampere and "V" for volt.. Current is measured in mA and capacity is measured in mAh. If you have an 18 V supply you won't be easily able to make the voltage adjustable all the way to 18 V. You will drop some voltage across the regulator. Is 14 or 15 V enough for you?

Comment: Current draw is in mA or A or amps not mAh. Try again. Why don’t you use a pot in the opamp circuit to control gain like 99.999 % of other distortion pedals?

Comment: Capacity (mAh) isn't your problem. Voltage is. Can you answer Andy's comment? He's a guitarist too.

Comment: If I add a 3rd battery making my input voltage 27V would I be able to get 9V minimum 18V maximim on something similar to a potemtometer, sorry I'm dosing in and out of sleep so I'm typing a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm new to this terminology I've played drums for years and worked on cars for years I'm just starting out in the guitar world and really just getting started in the modding world, please forgive my errors the terminology is still new to me especially the abbreviations I'm not trying to control gain (I have a boost installed for that) I'm trying to control clipping At will I like the clean channel sounds of my pickup's both at 9V and 18V on just looking for a smoother way to transition the two settings without a popping toggle switch in favor of something adjustable like a pot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question gives no clue regarding the voltage available for the task and the maximum current required. Assuming that there's a few volts to spare and that the current is < 100 mA a simple solution would be to use the ancient LM317 adjustable voltage regulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH13D8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Adjustable voltage regulator circuit.*

The LM317 adjusts its output so that it is 1.25 V higher than the ADJ pin. I have chosen the resistor values to make the maths easy (100 Ω/volt) so you can scale them up to use a 1k pot for R3, etc.

You'll need to calculate the power dissipation in U1 and check if you need a heatsink. \$ P = (V_{in+} - V_{OUT
min}) I \$.

Comment: side question; why did you use 125 ohm resistor for R1 when suggested resistor for R1 is 240 ohm?

Comment: So that I could use 100 Ω/volt in my calculations and to make it obvious what was going on. I didn't even refer to a datasheet. Using a lower value will just consume a little more power so if it's battery powered the datasheet recommendation would be better.

Comment: I added to the question I hope it helps.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same approach, but with one of the newer, low-dropout, low-static-current linear regulator chips to extend battery life.  Linear Technology (now a part of Analog Devices) has a pile of them.

Comment: @AnalogKid what do you mean?, do you have a link? Is this a pre-assembled piece or does it require soldering?

Comment: The devices to which AnalogKid is referring are regulator ICs which will require additional components, some means of connection (typically a PCB) and soldering. The result will be similar to my answer but with less voltage drop across the regulator.